# gulp copy source files from another drive

Tags: path, gulp

Hi I have piece of gulp snippet that works great and copies entire folders when the source and destination folders are on the same drive. If I try to run it to copy files from another drive say D:/path/to/project with an absolute path to the folder, the code runs without any errors but no files are copied.

```
`So the path = '../../myproject/' works while 'd:/path/to/Project' does not.
```

Any idea how this can be achieved in gulp?
Thanks.

**UPDATED WITH CODE**

Of the two paths, the first one, targeting folder in drive f, fails to copy while the 2nd one does so successfully. Has to be tried one at a time, commenting the other.

```
subB = 'src/webtest'
subC = 'pro_miles/eb_aws'

var pathsToProj = [
                   ['f:/pro_miles/eb_aws/**/*.*', '/src/'+subC, 'src/'+subC]
        //         ['../../pro_miles/eb_aws/**/*.*', '/src/'+subC, 'src/'+subC]
                 ]; 

`// gulp.task('copyFiles', function (cb) {`

tasks = function copyFiles(cb) {
  var paths = new Array();  
  for (const pathToProj of pathsToProj) {
    paths.push(gulp.src(pathToProj[0], {base: pathToProj[1]})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToProj[2])));
  };
  cb();
  return paths  
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(tasks) );
```

Comment: It works for me, you should show your copy task just in case.

Comment: Updated with code. Kindly take a look. thanks.